# parse sql queries in python

Tags: python, parsing

I want to be able to take a string like below and pull out the first parameter (`id`) and then use that to print it out. I have been looking into split for python, but I usually have to split 2 or 3 times before getting something usable.

Here is an example of the strings I am trying to parse:

```
EntryError(u"(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed:
role.name, role.domain_id [SQL: u'INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, 
domain_id, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('id', 
'fake1name', '<<null>>', '{}')]",)
```

I have tries things like:

```
e = e.split("\'")
e = e.split(",")
```

But this gives me weird strings that have to further be parsed. Is there an easier way to always pull the `id` from `"[parameters: ('id', 'fake1name', '<<null>>', '{}')]"`?

Here's the code I have:

```
except exception.EntryError as e:   

    query = str(e)
    # example of me using split to try and reduce the string
    parsedstr = query.split("[")
    parsedstr = parsedstr.split("\'")

    # This will give me id like I want but it doesn't seem efficient
    # prints: id
    print parsedstr[1]
```

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code - do you actually have access to the cursor or the exception instance itself? Thanks.

Comment: What string are you trying to parse? Are you actually trying to parse the message in the EntryError object above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.

```
import re

...

except exception.EntryError as e:
    print re.search("\[parameters: \('([^']+)", str(e)).group(1)
```

This would search the exception string for the first occurrence of `[parameters: ('` and start matching from that point until it hits a `'`.